# Analytic functions with real and imaginary parts

Tags: complex-analysis

Find all the analytic functions for which

$Im(z)=Re(f(z))$.

I know that a function is analytic in a domain if it is differentiable everywhere in that domain but I don't know where to go with the question.

I know that letting $z=x+iy$ then $Re(z)=x$ and $Im(z)=y$ but without a function to go on I don't know what $Re(f(z))$ is.

Comment: $f(z) = -iz$ works

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it helps to write $z = x+iy$ and $f(z) = u(x,y) + i v(x,y)$.

You want $Re(f(z)) = Im(z)$, so you must have $u(x,y) = y$.

Do you know the Cauchy-Riemann equations? This will allow you to determine $v$.

Comment: I know that the Cauchy-Riemann equations say that the partial derivative of u wrt x is equal to the partial derivative of v wrt y and the other way around at z=x+iy but how does that determine v?

Comment: You need to think about this a little harder. You know that $u(x,y) = y$. What is $u_x$? What is $u_y$?